# BizTalk mapping to excel

Tags: biztalk

Is there a way to convert or get the mapping from BizTalk map to an excel or a text file. From where we can directly see what field is mapped to what filed instead of following the lines. I have an BizTalk map which had around 600 fields mapped.

any pointers will be really helpful.

EDIT: My attempt to solve my problem: http://bmc.codeplex.com/

Comment: Created a small application which will parse my BTM file and give me an excel file with all the mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a small application which will parse my BTM file and give me an excel file with all the mapping. Uploaded the same to http://bmc.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can look [here](http://www.codeplex.com/BizTalkDocumenter) at the BizTalk documenter that will provide help-style documentaiton on many BizTalk artifacts including maps.  You can also just take a text editor and look at the XSLT that is created but with such a large map that can be a daunting task.  I've heard of some developers creating there own XSLT to convert the maps XSLT into a table like format but I cannot find any of that code off hand.  I'll search around and see if I can find another way as well.

You can also look [here](http://www.soft-r-us.com/biz/doc/display.asp?state=2) but I honestly haven't use this before so its at your own risk on what it outputs.

-Bryan

Answer (score 0):

XSLT isn't a tabular format that would be represented well in a spreadsheet.  It would be possible for simple mappings, but any time transformations are created or multiple fields joined to one, or one split to many, it just gets messy.

If it is a simple mapping, then a script that translates to XSLT into a CSV format is probably the easiest to get it into Excel.  Unless you want to load it into a DOM and use the Excel objects to build it directly.  Unless this isn't a one time thing, that is probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Open your xsl file in MS Excel.
It will ask to convert to xml. Then press **Yes** and it's done.